# Uploading TXT to dropbox

Tags: android, file-upload, dropbox

I started exploring Android app developing and I'm trying to upload a plain txt file to dropbox to start off. Whenever I've got this working I'll go up a level to pdf etc.

Anyways I keep running stuck in uploading to dropbox.
I've included the libraries, got the activity in my AndroidManifest and tried to follow the official guide as good as I can.
Without further nonsense, this is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
  <intent-filter>
    <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
    <data android:scheme="db-mykeyhere" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Layout file where I trigger the onclick to upload on:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HelloDropboxActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dropbox_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/link_button"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My activity:

```
public class Settings extends Activity{

    final static private String APP_KEY = "myAppKeyIsHere";
    final static private String APP_SECRET = "myAppSecretIsHere";
    final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;

    // In the class declaration section:
    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings); 


        // And later in some initialization function:
        AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    }


public void dropbox_button(View v){
        mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(Settings.this);

         String filePath = getApplicationContext()
                          .getFilesDir()
                          .getPath()
                          .toString() + "/magnus-opus.txt";

         File file = new File(filePath);


         try {
             file.createNewFile();
         } catch (IOException e2) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e2.printStackTrace();
         }
         FileInputStream inputStream = null;

         try {
             inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
         try {
             Entry response = mDBApi.putFile("/magnum-opus.txt", inputStream,
                     file.length(), null, null);
             Log.i("DbExampleLog",
                   "The uploaded file's rev is: " + response.rev);
         } catch (DropboxException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Required to complete auth, 
                // sets the access token on the session
                mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

                AccessTokenPair tokens = mDBApi
                                         .getSession()
                                         .getAccessTokenPair();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally my error log:
[image]

Could anybody tell me whats wrong here or help me ahead?
For now I just want to be able to upload a .txt file to my dropbox with ANYTHING in it.
Thanks

~Yenthe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a NoClassDefFound so it sounds like the library isn't properly included. How did you add the library?

Comment: Rightclick on project > properties > java build path tab > add external JAR's.
Here's the example:
http://imgur.com/rKrhd6b

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Eclipse so I'm not sure at the method for adding a jar library, hopefully someone else will, but I've had the NoClassDefFound error as it was because the library wasn't properly added.

Comment: Dang haha, well you probably gave me a hint into the right way. Hope somebody else knows the answer! Thanks for your time!

Comment: No worries, sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Guess you where pretty right. I did add them by add external JAR's but I also had too add them to the 'libs' folder myself. So you both need to add the external JAR's AND upload them to the 'libs' folder.
Thanks Tom :)